# Sprites in IE are not drawn correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-sprites

In my application, I have a few icons that are drawn on every page. For performance reasons, I have them grouped into a single file and drawn as [CSS sprites](http://alistapart.com/article/sprites). For some reason, IE will occassionally draw them incorrectly. If you zoom in on the image, it looks like IE is off by 1 pixel.

- This only happens in IE, does not happen in Chrome.
- The behavior in IE is inconsistent. For some people, the icons are drawn correctly.

Here is some sample CSS:

```
.bannerIconLogout {
    height: 13px;
    width: 12px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/common-images.png']}");
    background-position: 0px -13px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;   
}
```

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: The version of IE?

Comment: IE 11. The about box says Version: 11.0.9600.18524. Update Versions: 11.0.37.

Comment: f12>Emulation tab, which emulation mode is it using? expected Edge (aka IE11) and how was it established? (listed on the Emulation tab)
File>Properties will tell you which IE security zone your dev/test environments are mapped to. Commonly localhost may be mapped to the Intranet zone and causing a lower emulation mode in IE.
or
try adding boxsizing:border-box to the style rules for .bannerIconLogout
If you use the chrome dev tool to inspect the element you will see UserAgent Styles ..... copy those style rules to your stylesheet so that all browsers will assume the same default rules.

Comment: I don't think it's a browser mode problem. It's inconsistent within the same page. I am using sprites to draw 4 tabs on the page. 3 of them are drawn OK, and the 4th is incorrect. I'm wondering if it's some kind of rounding error.